# MySQL Lookup Table + Multiple Constraints in one Lookup Table

Tags: mysql

I have a table called users which has around 50 columns and I need to add constraints to around 30 of the 50 columns. Typically in the past I would create 30 constraint tables and apply each to the users table as Foreign Key constraint.

I wanted to see if I could just use one table for 30 constraints?

This would be one table with an incrementing primary key and 30 columns - one for each constraint. Some Constraints are around 5 entries and some around 100 entries so there would be NULL data in some of the constraint lists.

Is this a realistic way to do multiple constraints or do I need to use one table per constraint?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by constraint you mean lookup tables, then no, I would not combine them into a single table. If one of the fields has 2 possible values and another one has 3, then for the first one you would still have 3 choices available in the lookup table, even if the 3rd choice is linked to null.

If you are worried about the number of lookup tables, then consider using mysql's enum data type instead.

Comment: yes I meant lookup tables - thanks for your time... So I assume the issue with a multi column lookup table like this is the presence of NULL.